# </form>タグの位置によってセレクトボックスの中が表示されなくなる

Tags: html

お住まいの場所によって変動する複数の選択肢を、formでメール送信できるページを作ろうとしています
送って欲しい情報は「名前」「メールアドレス」「お住まい」「第一希望」「第二希望」です

例Aの人）
お住まい：東京
第一希望：①②③（3つの選択肢から選べる
第二希望：①②③（3つの選択肢から選べる

例Bの人）
お住まい：大阪
第一希望：③④⑤（３つの選択肢から選べる
第二希望：③④⑤（３つの選択肢から選べる

セレクトボックスも表示されるのですが、
タイトル記載の通り、で閉じる位置によってセレクトボックスの中が空白になります

暫く奮闘しましたが、判らなかったのでお知恵を拝借させて頂けないでしょうか

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sample</title>

<link href="modal-multi.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="./js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<!-- Crayon Syntax Highlighter v_2.7.2_beta -->
<!-- [Format Time: 0.0002 seconds] -->


<div id="wapper" class="clearfix">
<hgroup id="site-title">
<div id="logo">
<!-- メールフォーム -->
<body bgcolor="black"text="silver" overflow: hidden;">
<br><br>
<div id="formWrap">

<form method="post" action="mail01.php">
<table class="formTable">
<tr><td><font size="2">お名前
      <td><input size="35" type="text" name="お名前" /><font size="2">※必須</td></tr>
<tr><td><font size="2">Mail
      <td><input size="35" type="text" name="Email" /> <font size="2">※必須</td></tr>
<tr><td>

</table>


<!--ココに</form>があればセレクトボックスは問題なく表示されるが、下記の希望の日時が送れない事になる-->


<Div Align="left">
<div class="result">
<select id="selPref" style="width:250px;margin:15px;" onchange="selPref(this);"></select><br><br>
<font size="2">
●第一希望の日時
<select id="selCity" style="width:250px;margin:15px;"></select><br>
●第二希望の日時
<select id="selCityy" style="width:250px;margin:15px;"></select><br>
●第三希望の日時
<select id="selCityyy" style="width:250px;margin:15px;"></select><br>
</div>



<p align="center">
<input type="submit" value="　 確認 　" />　<input type="reset" value="リセット" />
</p></form></div>




</body>

<script>//選択
var arr = [
{cd:"", label:"住所を選択"},
{cd:"13", label:"東京都"},
{cd:"30", label:"埼玉県、千葉県"},

];

//市区の選択肢
var arrTokyo = [
{cd:"", label:"希望の日時を選択"},
{cd:"1", label:"10月10日 日曜日 ①9:00~15:00"},{cd:"2", label:"10月10日 日曜日 ②15:00~21:00"},{cd:"3", label:"10月23日 土曜日 ①9:00~15:00"},
{cd:"4", label:"10月23日 土曜日 ②15:00~21:00"},{cd:"5", label:"10月24日 日曜日 ①9:00~15:00"},{cd:"6", label:"10月24日 日曜日 ②15:00~21:00"}　　];

var arrSaitamachiba = [
{cd:"", label:"希望の日時を選択"},
{cd:"1", label:"10月23日 土曜日 ①9:00~15:00"},{cd:"2", label:"10月23日 土曜日 ②15:00~21:00"},
{cd:"3", label:"10月24日 日曜日 ①9:00~15:00"},{cd:"4", label:"10月24日 日曜日 ②15:00~21:00"},   ];



window.onload=function(){
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
let op = document.createElement("option");
op.value = arr[i].cd;
op.text = arr[i].label;
document.getElementById("selPref").appendChild(op);
  }
}

//都府県が選択された時に呼び出される処理
function selPref(obj){
  var targetArr;
if(obj.value == "13"){targetArr = arrTokyo;}
else if(obj.value == "30"){targetArr = arrSaitamachiba;}




else{targetArr = new Array();}

  var selObj = document.getElementById('selCity');
  while(selObj.lastChild){
    selObj.removeChild(selObj.lastChild);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<targetArr.length;i++){
    let op = document.createElement("option");
    op.value = targetArr[i].cd;
    op.text = targetArr[i].label;
    selObj.appendChild(op);
  }

  var selObj = document.getElementById('selCityy');
  while(selObj.lastChild){
    selObj.removeChild(selObj.lastChild);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<targetArr.length;i++){
    let op = document.createElement("option");
    op.value = targetArr[i].cd;
    op.text = targetArr[i].label;
    selObj.appendChild(op);
  }

  var selObj = document.getElementById('selCityyy');
  while(selObj.lastChild){
    selObj.removeChild(selObj.lastChild);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<targetArr.length;i++){
    let op = document.createElement("option");
    op.value = targetArr[i].cd;
    op.text = targetArr[i].label;
    selObj.appendChild(op);
  }

}
</script>
</html>
```

●追加情報

回答して頂いた方の助言をもとに、開発者ツールのコンソールを調べました
出ていたエラーは下記の通りでした

①0011.html:47 Uncaught TypeError: selPref is not a function
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (0011.html:47)

これらの情報をもとに並行して自身でも調べてみますが、もしお分かりなる方が居るようでしたら、助言、お知恵を拝借させて頂けると助かります
宜しくお願いします

Comment: <select>は4つあるようですが、「空白になる」のはどれでしょうか?

Comment: あと、問題が発生したときに、ブラウザの開発者ツールのコンソールになにかエラーは出ていますか?

Comment: 言葉足らずで失礼しました
4つある<select>の内、空白となるのは
●第一希望の日時
●第二希望の日時
●第三希望の日時

の３つです

開発者ツールのコンソールという機能を知らなかったので、すぐに調べてコメントに記載させて頂きます

Comment: タグ　hgroup　body　div　font　が閉じられていない所があります。id名と　 javascript関数名は分けましょう。最新のコード記述を心がけましょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<select id="selPref" style="width:250px;margin:15px;" onchange="selPref(this);"></select><br><br>
```

解決策はいくつかありますが、簡単なのは**関数 `selPref()` の名前をなにか別のものに変える**ことです。

古風な `onchange` 属性ではなく、`addEventListener()` を使うことでも直ります。この場合は関数名を変える必要はありません。

```js
document.querySelector('#selPref').addEventListener('change', selPref);
//都府県が選択された時に呼び出される処理
function selPref(event){
  let obj = event.target;
```

---

解説:

`onchange` など、on〜 によるイベントハンドラのコードでは、シンボルの検索順序が通常と異なります。`selPref` というシンボルがあって、ターゲット要素が`<form>`と繋がっていない場合、

1. `this.selPref` (thisはHTMLSelectElementで、`this.selPref`は存在しない)
2. `window.selPref` (これが関数)

この順番で検索されるので、意図通り `selPref()` 関数が呼ばれます。

ターゲット要素が`<form>`と繋がっている場合は順序が変わり、

1. `this.selPref`
2. `this.form.selPref`
3. `window.selPref`

になります。`this.form` は繋がっている `<form>` で、HTMLFormElement には繋がっている要素の `name` 属性値と `id` 属性値のプロパティが自動的に付与されるので、2番目の `this.form.selPref` は `<select id="selPref" ...>` を指すことになります。よって、「`selPref` は関数ではない」というエラーになるわけです。

Comment: int32_tさん
御丁寧に、有難う御座います ご教示頂いた情報を基に、書き直した結果、出来ました
どうも有難う御座います、お手上げだったので、とても助かりました 本当にありがとうございます ただ、そこから、いざ送信をしようとすると
しっかり記入したにも関わらず
「名前が未設定です」となって送信できない為に
恐らくmail.phpとの兼ね合いで別の問題が発生しているように思います ここからは、タイトルとは反れる内容となってしまう為に
自身でまた試行錯誤して、厳しかった場合、改めて質問をさせて頂きたいと思っております 此度は貴重なお時間を割いてまで、助言を有難うございました